# Create a mixin for interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mixins

```
interface IBase {
  baseProp?: string;
}

class Base implements IBase {
  baseProp: string = "baseProp";
}

type AnyClass<T> = new () => T;

interface IClass1 extends IBase {
  class1Prop?: string;
}

const Class1Mixin = (MixedClasses: AnyClass<any>): AnyClass<IClass1> =>
  class extends MixedClasses implements IClass1 {
    class1Prop: string = "class1Prop";
  };

interface IClass2 extends IBase {
  class2Prop?: string;
}

const Class2Mixin = (MixedClasses: AnyClass<any>): AnyClass<IClass2> =>
  class extends MixedClasses implements IClass2 {
    class2Prop: string = "class2Prop";
  };

// Mix classes
const mix = <T>(...extensions: Array<(anyClass: any) => AnyClass<T>>) => {
  let Composition = Base as AnyClass<IBase>;

  for (const ext of extensions) {
    Composition = ext(Composition);
  }
  return Composition as AnyClass<T>;
};

// Here can be any number of classes
const Mixed = mix(Class1Mixin, Class2Mixin);
const mixedInit = new Mixed();
// Now mixedInit is IBase & ICLass1
// and I need that it will be IBase & ICLass1 & ICLass2

console.log(mixedInit.baseProp, mixedInit.class1Prop, mixedInit.class2Prop);
```

I have a function that mixes any number of classes all together with Base class. But I couldn't mix interfaces of theses classes. Please tell me how can I improve mix function types to do that?

Comment: The closest thing would be [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), but `interfaces` and `class`es cannot be mixed using functions as `interface`s are purely types with no values attached to them (contrary to `enums` and `class`es)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is solution.The essence of this solution is transform union type to intersection type.You can read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10621270) about the question of transform union type to intersection type

```js
interface IBase {
  baseProp?: string;
}

class Base implements IBase {
  baseProp: string = "baseProp";
}

type AnyClass<T> = new () => T;

interface IClass1 extends IBase {
  class1Prop?: string;
}

const Class1Mixin = (MixedClasses: AnyClass<any>): AnyClass<IClass1> =>
  class extends MixedClasses implements IClass1 {
    class1Prop: string = "class1Prop";
  };

interface IClass2 extends IBase {
  class2Prop?: string;
}

const Class2Mixin = (MixedClasses: AnyClass<any>): AnyClass<IClass2> =>
  class extends MixedClasses implements IClass2 {
    class2Prop: string = "class2Prop";
  };


type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

// Modified Mix classes
const mix = <T extends Array<(MixedClasses: AnyClass<any>) => AnyClass<any>>>(...extensions: T): AnyClass<UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<ReturnType<T[number]>>>> => {
  let Composition = Base as AnyClass<IBase>;

  for (const ext of extensions) {
    Composition = ext(Composition);
  }
  return Composition as any;
};

const Mixed = mix(Class1Mixin, Class2Mixin);
const mixedInit = new Mixed();
// Now mixedInit is ICLass1 & ICLass2

console.log(mixedInit.baseProp, mixedInit.class1Prop, mixedInit.class2Prop);
```

Comment: You are best of the best 8) Thanks.
Maybe you can help me with one thing:

`type AnyClass<T> = new (config?: T['config']) => T;`

How could be config key extracted from T without error?

Comment: @EEM Try to declare the essential of T type.Example:  `type AnyClass<T extends { config: any }> = new (config?: T['config']) => T`